# Why does my HP printer keep getting stuck on the last page when printing on Linux?

Tags: linux, printing, cups, hplip

I have an HP inkjet printer with a duplex printing attachment. Whenever I print a document with an odd number of pages, the last page gets "stuck", and the only way to reset the printer is to actually unplug it (the power button doesn't work).

This only happened after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 (from 14.04), doing a complete reinstall. With 14.04 I didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to go into printer settings and remove the printer, and then re-add it, making sure to choose "HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP)" rather than "USB" as the Connection.

Even if the printer is physically connected with USB, selecting the "USB" option when setting up the printer causes trouble with duplex.